# Setting Page Design field in Sitecore pages

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'd like to set the Page Design field in certain pages of a certain template to a value in sitecore using powershell script. I tried the following but it didn't work. I also tried the name of the page design itself instead of the ID but also didn't work.

```
cd 'master:/sitecore/content/'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -match "{TemplateName}"} | ForEach-Object {   
    $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $_.Fields["Page Design"].Value = "{000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000}";
    $_.Editing.EndEdit()
    ""
}
```

Comment: what sort of error comes up?

Comment: no errors...the value just isn't set

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do it. I was able to do it using the following script

```powershell
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path '/sitecore/content/' -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "TemplateName"}

foreach($item in $items){
    $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $item["Page Design"] = "{000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000}";
    $item.Editing.EndEdit()
}
```