# How do you programmatically change the "Quick Action Bar" of a template to "Required" using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-extensions

Can someone please provide an example using SPE to set the field "Quick Action Bar" of my templates to required "Required"?

[image: SPE that will set the Field "Quick Action Bar"]

Comment: Try to use search next time. Example https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/16130/16

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the documentation [here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items) you can set properties using the automatic property setters/getters.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path master:/content/home
$item.Title = "New Title"
$item."Closing Date" = [datetime]::Today
```

As pointed out in the comments from Alan, you can use the example seen in a previous question.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path master:/content/home
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item["SomeProperty"] = "{000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000}";
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```